# Measuring length and width of object using Android's accelerometer and gyroscope

Tags: android, width, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

we are proposing a project of measuring the length and width of object using android's accelerometer and gyroscope sensors. 
we plan to implement it by simply hovering the smartphone over the object, with start and stop buttons.
i know there are a lot of articles about measuring distance but there isnt an exact one about measuring lengt and width, added to the fact that measuring distance using these 2 sensors give out measurements with great error percentages and need filters like kalman.

so in this day, is it possible for us to accurately measure objects using these 2 sensors?

Answer (score 0):

Both the gyro and the accelerometer measure rates of change. i.e. derivatives of distance and/or angle.  Integrating these values to get distances (length) is very noisy and errors accumulate very very fast. So unless you have some additional way to correct for drift errors your measurements will quickly become irrelevant.

GPS and magnetometer, measure absolute values relative to some global frame of reference.  If your distances are large enough, then you may be able to use these as absolute reference points.